# could not find recipe epel for cookbook yum

Tags: nginx, yum, chef, epel, cookbook

i am having trouble with nginx cookbook.. and it dependency on yum-epel.

Getting error :

### " Chef::Exceptions::RecipeNotFound

could not find recipe epel for cookbook yum"

```
$ knife cookbook show nginx nginx   2.7.6  2.7.5  2.7.4  1.8.0
$ knife cookbook show yum-epel yum-epel   0.6.6  0.6.0
$ knife cookbook show yum yum   3.10.0  3.6.0  3.5.4  3.5.3  3.5.2
```

Been looking around, Looks like :

> there was a major upstream release of the yum cookbook (3.X) that
>   moved yum::epel recipe to a new yum-epel cookbook.

But can't find a workaround to apply.
I am using berks to resolve the cookbook dependencies.

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You need to run yum < 3.0.0  to get the yum::epel recipe. Add that dependency somewhere in your environment or top-level cookbook to work around it.

In metadata.rb parlance:
depends 'yum', '< 3.0.0'